# Open application in last state it was in

Tags: android

when the user clicks on the icon in the app drawer to start my application, my app opens in the state it was last in.

I have a broadcast receiver, and when I receive a certain intent I want to have the same effect.

At the moment I use

```
Intent launchIntent = mContext.getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("xx.xx.xx"); //My package name
context.startActivity(launchIntent);
```

But this always opens the mainactivity of my application.

How can I fix this? thx